# On the fundamental domain of an action

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, spheres, isometry

Let $\Gamma$ be a group os isometries of $\mathbb{S}^n$ acting properly and discontinuously. For $p \neq q \in \mathbb{S}^n$, define

$$H_{p,q} = \{ x \in \mathbb{S}^n : d(p, x) < d(q, x) \},$$

where $d$ is the distance function on $\mathbb{S}^n$. The fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ centered at $p$ is then

$$\Delta_p = \bigcap_{g \in G \setminus \{e\}} H_{p, g(p)}.$$

Facts about $\Delta_p$ can be found on [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178241180). For example, $\Delta_p$ is open and star-like with respect to $p$. My question is: **does it always happen that the antipodal point of $p$ does not lie in $\overline{\Delta}_p$ when $\Gamma$ is not trivial?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following facts, found on the above cited paper, I prove that $-p \not \in \overline{\Delta}_p$.

**Fact 1:**  $\partial \Delta_p = \bigcup_{g \neq e} \partial \Delta_p \cap \partial \Delta_{g(p)}$

**Fact 2:**  $\overline{\Delta}_p \cap \overline{\Delta}_{g(p)} \subset A_{p, g(p)}$, where $A_{p,g(p)} = \{ x \in \mathbb{S}^n : d(p, x) = d(g(p), x)\}$.

Suppose $-p \in \overline{\Delta}_p$. We divide in two cases

**Case 1:** $-p \in \Delta_p$. In this case, we would have, for each $g\neq e$,

$$\pi = d(p, -p) < d(g(p), -p),$$

absurd.

**Case 2:** $-p \in \partial \Delta_p$. In this case, from the facts above, we conclude that there exists $g_0 \in \Gamma, g_0 \neq e$, such that $-p \in \partial \Delta_p \cap \partial \Delta_{g_0(p)} \subset A_{p,g_0(p)}$. Thus, from

$$\pi = d(p, -p) = d(g_0(p), -p)$$

we conclude that $g_0(p) = p$, which cannot occur, since no element of $\Gamma$ has a fixed point.